# Как добавить к каждому изображению логотип без правки html и картинок?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, изображения

Всем привет! Есть  сайт с галереей изображений, которые добавляются динамически.
Как можно добавить к каждому изображению логотип в png не исправляя html и не внося правки в сами картинки?

```css
.gallery .row {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.gallery .row img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
max-width:284px;
max-height:333px;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
.gallery .row img::before {
  background: url(../../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <? u_img(3101); ?>
      <p>
        <? u_txt(3101); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <? u_img(3102); ?>
      <p>
        <? u_txt(3102); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <? u_img(3103); ?>
      <p>
        <? u_txt(3103); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `::after` or `::before`, JS...

Comment: вот так?
.gallery .row img::before {
      background: url(../../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
но почему-то не срабатывает...

Comment: Без примера Вашего кода подсказать вряд ли возможно. Там нужно определить, спозиционировать и разместить правильно.

Comment: привел фрагмент кода

Comment: :before и :after не работает с img

Comment: и как же тогда возможно это обойти?

Comment: если я добавлю js
$('.gallery .row img').each(function() { $(this).wrap("<div class="watermark"></div>"); });
и css
.watermark {
background: url(../../images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
сработает?

Comment: проверил. неа, что-то и это не помогает..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```js
$('.gallery img').wrap('<div class="imagewrapper">');
```

```css
.gallery .row {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.gallery .row img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:284px;
    max-height:333px;
    background: #ccc;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
.imagewrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width:284px;
    max-height:333px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.imagewrapper:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/128px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    margin: -64px 0 0 -64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B52SQ8GCEAIJ4fy.jpg" alt="" />
            <p>
                <? u_txt(3101); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B52SQ8GCEAIJ4fy.jpg" alt="" />
            <p>
                <? u_txt(3102); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B52SQ8GCEAIJ4fy.jpg" alt="" />
            <p>
                <? u_txt(3103); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо тебе огромное, soledar10!

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы логотип не мешал открытию картинки?

Comment: .imagewrapper:before -  pointer-events: none;

Comment: Блеск, soledar10! только ie 10 и ниже не будут поддерживать сюдя по can i use

Comment: просто добавить полифил? 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/pep/0.3.0/pep.js"></script>

Comment: да - https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill